# Perl how to take advantage of a block argument in my subroutine (like grep does)

Tags: perl, function, block, argument-passing

grep can be invoked in two ways as listed below. I properly miss a piece of information to understand this block magic. Maybe a good soul can explain to me how grep internal gets a reference to the block and deals with that or even better how can I write a subroutine which uses the bock notation.

1) This is what I consider the traditional way.
grep EXPR,LIST
example: `@foo = grep(!/^#/, @bar);`
2) This is nice and neat but magic to me.
grep BLOCK LIST 
example: `@foo = grep {!/^#/} @bar;`

Many thanks in advance.

BR/Hermann

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [prototypes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes)

```
sub mygrep (&@) {
  my $f = shift;

  return map { $f->() ? $_ : () } @_;
}

print join "\n", mygrep { $_%2 } 1..10;
```

Same thing as above, but without prototypes,

```
sub mygrep {
  my $f = shift;

  return map { $f->() ? $_ : () } @_;
}

print join "\n", mygrep( sub{ $_%2 }, 1..10 );
```

Comment: It's also worth looking at [Params::Lazy](https://metacpan.org/pod/Params::Lazy) which allows you to write a `mygrep` function that has both a block and expression form (like the real `grep` does).

Comment: @tobyink perhaps, but also `PREREQUISITES: Perl 5.14.0 or higher, although 5.18.0 is recommended to get the most stable behavior`